# How use fastlane to deploy xamarin.forms to both iOS and Android?

Tags: deployment, xamarin.forms, fastlane, visual-studio-app-center

Now I'm ready to deploy to beta testers an app with Xamarin.Forms. I wonder if fastlane is the right tool.

I have found small pieces in how do this:

Only for iOS:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/provisioning/fastlane/

but not show how build the project first or how select the IPA/apk.

For appcenter:

https://github.com/Microsoft/fastlane-plugin-appcenter

But expect to have the IPA/apk already.

Answer (score 3):

Use `msbuild` to build both your [Android](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/ci/jenkins_walkthrough/#Building_a_Xamarin.Android_Project) and [iOS](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/ci/jenkins_walkthrough/#Compiling_a_Xamarin.iOS_Applications) app. Afterwards you can upload the IPA with [`fastlane deliver`](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/deliver/) to iTunes Connect and the APK with [`fastlane supply`](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/supply/) to Google Play Console.